# Draw bitmap with opengl in lazarus

Tags: opengl, pascal, freepascal, lazarus

I installed opengl component for Lazarus (OpenGLControl). I wonder how I can draw on this surface simple bitmap.
So far I draw bitmap on PaintBox like this:

```
myBitmap := TBitmap.Create();
myBitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
myBitmap.LoadFromFile('image.bmp');
myBitmap.width := 13000;
myBitmap.height:= 7000;

PaintBox.Canvas.Draw(0,0,myBitmap);
```

How I should do this with opengl? Can I just simple draw on OpenGL component?

Comment: Don't think you can draw it that way. That is canvas draw. Which paint the bitmap onto the form. OpenGL is another dimension really. And with openGL you should add a polygon (plane) to the world and then, apply that bitmap as texture to that plane object.

Comment: I learnt opengl on delphi years ago and I refer to NeHe tutorial. they are good to learn opengl: https://nehe.gamedev.net